# Async Callback - Placing the Call Back Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous

New to Js and trying to work out Async-callbacks in a non-server based setting.  As an example I've created two functions, the first of which calls the second.  The first function is triggered by an `onclick` event, which starts a 1 second timer, and then an alert shows.

What I am trying to have happen is after that alert, another 3 seconds passes and the second alert function should fire. However, I am unsure of how to call the second function correctly.

Below is my code.  Any help would be appreciated

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 var square = $('.square');
 
 square.on('click', function(callbackFunction) {
  setTimeout(function() {
   alert('Thanks for waiting');
  }, 1000);
  
  callbackFunction(); //end of callback function
 });//end of square click
 
 function callbackFunction() {
  setTimeout(function() {
   alert('thanks for waiting even longer')
  }, 3000);
 };
 
 
});//end of doc
```

```css
.square {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border: 1px solid;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: you can put `callbackFunction();` right below the first alert. That way, the callback gets called after 1 second, which in turn starts the 3 seconds timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control the signature of the callback function of the event listener, so you cannot pass it a function. It is always passed a copy of the event itself, so we usually write it like this:

```
square.on('click', function(event) {

});
```

Some people use `e` instead of `event`, doesn't really matter the name, but it is always a copy of the event.

When you call a function, your calling code will stop there, execute the function, get the returned value (if any), and then continue. But when you call an async function, your code will call the function and continue without waiting for it to finish. Since your code didn't wait for the function, it cannot get its returned value or any indication that it is done. To get that, we use a callback function, which is called by the async function when it completes its job. It's like saying, do your job and call me back when done.

Back to the `click` event above, the second argument accepts a function as a callback function. It's like saying: when the event occurs (somebody clicks on the element), call this callback function. We can pass it an anonymous function (a function with no name), like in the example above, or we pass it the name of a function like this:

square.on('click', callbackFunction);

Notice that we only pass the name, no parenthesis. Because we're not executing the function, we're just telling the event listener the name of the function that it needs to call when the event happens.

Here is the full code fixed. I renamed your functions to be clearer. The second function is not a callback function and we call it directly:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.square').on('click', callbackFunction);

  function callbackFunction() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert('Thanks for waiting');
      secondFunction(); //calling the second function
    }, 1000);

  }

  function secondFunction() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert('thanks for waiting even longer')
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

```css
.square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass your callback to your click handler, then I would do it as following:

```
function clickHandler(callbackFunction) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('Thanks for waiting');
        callbackFunction();
    }, 1000);
}

function callbackFunction() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('thanks for waiting even longer')
    }, 3000);
};

square.on('click', function()  {
    clickHandler(callbackFunction);
});
```

If you need just to show 2 alert after 1 one, then no param is needed:

```
function clickHandler() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('Thanks for waiting');
        callbackFunction();
    }, 1000);
}

function callbackFunction() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('thanks for waiting even longer')
    }, 3000);
};

square.on('click', clickHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  No, I don't need to show two alerts, I was just using alerts as a concept.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer to the question. *If you want to pass your callback to your click handler, then I would do it as following*, why would you do that? You didn't pass a callback function to the click handler, you passed it to a function that you called inside the handler. The handler itself is a callback function, so you simply pass it the name of the function. I will not downvote, but this is a bad example for callback functions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the way you set that up is here:

```
 square.on('click', function(callbackFunction) { ...
```

...you're passing an anonymous function as the 2nd param of jquery's `.on` .  Since this param is a valid function, jQuery calls it, passing an `events` object (representing details around the user's click action) in as the first parameter, which you have mis-named as "callbackFunction". The `events` object is not, itself, a function, so when you attempt to execute it like a function two lines later:

```
 callbackFunction();
```

it errors.

You didn't specify any browser requirements in your question, and since dhilt answered with more traditional js (+1), I thought I'd show how to solve this with more modern js syntax (using [es6 arrow functions](http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
     $('.square').on('click', () => setTimeout(() => {
         alert('thanks for waiting');
         setTimeout( () => alert('thanks for waiting even longer'), 3000 );
     }, 1000));
});
```